# Applying multiple summarize-operations in one pipeline while "re-using" dropped variables

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

My problem seems to be simple enough but I can't wrap my head around the problem and obviously don't know the appropriate search terms.

I have a data frame, and I want to apply multiple summarizations. The data looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:20),
                 year = sample(2015:2020, 20, replace = T),
                 Age_group = sample(c("20-29", "30-39", "40-49", "50-59"), 20, replace = T),
                 sex = sample(c("male", "female"), 20, replace = T),
                 count = sample(1:100, 20, replace = T))
```

In a single pipeline, I would like to summarize the data

1. by ID only, then
2. by ID and year, then
3. by ID, year, and age group …

I have looked into the `assign` function, the `%T>%` operator and `{<<-.}`, all of which helped me come a bit closer but no cigar, yet.

In my pseudo-R, it would look like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(sum_of_count = sum(count)) %>% -> "df with ID and sum_of_count"
  group_by(ID,year) %>% # keep working with the variable "year" which hasn't been dropped
  summarize(sum_of_count = sum(count)) %>% -> "df with ID, year and sum_of_count"
```

I would like a separate data.frame for each grouping as I would eventually combine them in a single Excel file on different sheets using the `rio::export()` function.

I am fine with any solution (i. e., additional packages etc.) that is only one block of code.

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Assuming that the summarize function is the same for all groups, one could try:

```r
list(
  df1 = "ID",
  df2 = c("ID","year")
) %>% lapply(function(gp){
  df %>% group_by_at(gp) %>% summarize(sum_of_count = sum(count))
}) %>% rio::export("output_file.xlsx")
```

here the `df1` and `df2` will determine the names of the Sheets in the exported `outpuf_file.xlsx`. Alternatively, the initial `list` can be left unnamed if the exported Sheet names do not matter.

Comment: Sorry for not making my desired output clear, I only implied it in my pseudo-code. I want my output to be a separate data.frame for each grouping as eventually I would like to output them all in a single Excel-file one different sheets using the `rio::export()` function. Using your solution, there would be quite a few steps in between.

Comment: @KlausPeter oh I see. is there any particular reason why do you want this in one code block specifically?

Comment: @KlausPeter see Edit, if it's closer to the expected output

Comment: This is a brilliant solution and leaner than I could have imagined. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to assign the result to three different `data.frame`s than one approach is to first create different views of the data by adding a "All" category to each grouping variable, and then attach those additional data sets with `bind_rows`. Then we can group by each data set (below `data`) and `group_map()` over each `data.frame`, naming them with `set_names()` and then assign them to the global environment with `bind_env()`.

Below I'm using the 'gapminder' data set, since its better than the original random data which only has one year row per ID.

Be careful with `bind_env()` since it assigns objects to the global environment (but my guess is that this is the goal).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>%
  mutate(year = as.character(year)) %>% 
  bind_rows(mutate(gapminder,
                   country = "All",
                   year = "All"),
            mutate(gapminder,
                   year = "Total"),
            .id = "data") %>% 
  group_by(data) %>% 
  group_map(~ .x %>%
              # here goes any summary statistic:
              summarise(n = n(),
                        .by = c(continent, country, year)
                        )
  ) %>% 
  set_names(nm = paste0("df", seq_along(.))) %>% 
  env_bind(.env = globalenv(),
           !!! .)

ls()
#> [1] "df1" "df2" "df3"

df2
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   continent country year      n
#>   <fct>     <chr>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 Asia      All     All     396
#> 2 Europe    All     All     360
#> 3 Africa    All     All     624
#> 4 Americas  All     All     300
#> 5 Oceania   All     All      24
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>